# What should I do to get pull query results? (Failed to scan materialized table)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

To summarize first, if you send a pull query, you will get an error message below.

```
Unable to execute pull query
Caused by: io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Error executing query locally
    at node http://our.host.com:8089/: Failed to scan
    materialized table
Caused by: Error executing query locally at node
    http://our.host.com:8089/: Failed to scan materialized
    table
Caused by: Failed to scan materialized table
Caused by: Cannot get state store Aggregate-Aggregate-Materialize because the
    stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING
```

The ksqlDb server with the same service.id has been uploaded to three servers. (Confluent Platform Community Eddition 7.0.0)
A stream with 9 partitions as a data source was created, and a table with that stream as a data source was created.

I will attach the relevant query below.

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS NEW_STREAM (A BIGINT, B BIGINT, C VARCHAR, D VARCHAR)
WITH (kafka_topic='exist.topic',
      key_format='KAFKA',
      value_format='JSON',
      partitions=9);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NEW_STREAM_TABLE WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='NEW_STREAM_TABLE', KEY_FORMAT='json', PARTITIONS=3, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='json') AS
SELECT
    A A_KEY,
    B B_KEY,
    C C_KEY,
    AS_VALUE(A) A,
    AS_VALUE(B) B,
    AS_VALUE(C) C,
    COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM NEW_STREAM WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 30 MINUTES)
GROUP BY A, B, C
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

**pull query**

```sh
ksql> select * from NEW_STREAM_TABLE;
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|A_KEY            |B_KEY         |C_KEY            |WINDOWSTART               |WINDOWEND                 |A                |B             |C                |COUNT                     |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
Unable to execute pull query
Caused by: io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Error executing query locally
    at node http://our.host.com:8089/: Failed to scan
    materialized table
Caused by: Error executing query locally at node
    http://our.host.com:8089/: Failed to scan materialized
    table
Caused by: Failed to scan materialized table
Caused by: Cannot get state store Aggregate-Aggregate-Materialize because the
    stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING
```

What should I do to get pull query results?

Comment: Hi, do you still experience this issue? Can you confirm the internal command topic is still running for this ksqldb?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in answering.
I solved the problem by creating it again after table drop, but it occurs intermittently. How should I check the status of the internal command topic?

Answer (score 0):

KSQL underlying logic uses [KafkaStreams](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html)

It seems that due to a consumer or producer subscribing or unsubscribing to a particular topic, the stream will "Rebalance" or redistribute partitions. This may be the reason for the final issue.

Sometimes a stream or consumer can get stuck in a rebalancing stage and never be allowed to be pulled from. I have experienced this issue myself and am currently trying to increase the rebalancing delay of the broker as described here: https://medium.com/bakdata/solving-my-weird-kafka-rebalancing-problems-c05e99535435

Hope that this is helpful, even though it is only my best guess as to what your issue may be.